# Kafka consumer status says "no active members" although I see my consumers ingesting logs

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-kafka-python

I am using kafka static partitioning to assign a consumer to a group example:
I have a `test-topic` with 3 partitions and I have manually made consumer1 connect to partition 0, consumer2 connect to partition 1, consumer3 connect to partition 2.

Using:

```
consumer.assign(TopicPartition(`test-topic`, 1))
consumer_configs = {'group.id': 'groupM'}
```

Note:
I have the same groupID for the 3 consumers

When, I deploy my application and I can see that the consumers are ingesting data and producting result files, the offsets are moving but I dont see any active members in the consumer group command

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server "localhost:9092" --describe --group groupM
```

I see

```
Consumer group 'groupM' has no active members.
```

What else can I try?

I have checked logs of the consumers I don't see restarts, used kafka-cli to monitor consumer status (unsuccesfully)

Answer (score 0):

The `group.id` config is not used there; when you use the consumer assign API, there is no consumer group.

You will only have a consumer group when you use `.subscribe`.